# How to Remove Directories From EnumerateFiles?

Tags: c#, file, directory, enumerate

So I'm working on a program that will list all the files in a directory. Pretty simple. Basically, when I do this: `List<string> dirs = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateFiles(target));`, I don't want it to include the directory and all. Just the file name. When I run my code;

```
    List<string> dirs = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateFiles(target));
    Console.WriteLine($"Folders and files in this directory:\n");
    foreach (string i in dirs) {
        Console.WriteLine($"> {i}");
    }
```

it gives me the following:

> C:\Users\Camden\Desktop\Programming\Visual Studio\C#\DirectoryManager\DirectoryManager\bin\Debug\DirectoryManager.exe

I just want the DirectoryManager.exe part, so I looked it up and I found that you can replace strings inside of strings. Like so: `i.Replace(target, "");`. However, this isn't doing anything, and it's just running like normal. Why isn't it replacing, and how should I instead do this?

Comment: Take a substring from last index of ‘\’

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Just use [```Path.GetFileName```](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename)

Answer (score 2):

Use methods from the System.IO.Path class.

```
        var fullfile = @"C:\Users\Camden\Desktop\Programming\Visual Studio\C#\DirectoryManager\DirectoryManager\bin\Debug\DirectoryManager.exe";
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullfile); // DirectoryManager.exe
        var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullfile);  // DirectoryManager
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use the Select IEnumerable extension
(you need to have a `using Linq;` at the top of your source code file)

```
List<string> files = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateFiles(target)
                                      .Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x)));
```

In this way the sequence of files retrieved by `Directory.EnumerateFiles` is passed, one by one, to the `Select` method where each fullfile name (x) is passed to `Path.GetFileName` to produce a new sequence of just filenames.
This sequence is then returned as a parameter to the List constructor.

And about your question on the Replace method. Remember that the Replace method doesn't change the string that you use to call the method, but returns a new string with the replacement executed. In NET strings are immutable.

So if you want to look at the replacement you need

```
string justFileName = i.Replace(target, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `Directory.EnumerateFiles`, would be [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413232(v=vs.110).aspx). This method returns an [`IEnumerable<FileInfo>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx). You can then make use of the `FileInfo.Name` property of each of the returned objects. Your code would then become:

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(target).EnumerateFiles(); 
Console.WriteLine("Files in this directory:\n"); 
foreach (FileInfo i in files) { 
    Console.WriteLine($"> {i.Name}"); 
}
```

For just the list of file names:

```
List<string> fileNames = new DirectoryInfo(target).EnumerateFiles().Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

Alternatively, if you want both files *and* directories, you can use [`EnumerateFileSystemInfos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383504(v=vs.110).aspx). If you need to know if you have a file vs a directory you can query the `Attributes` property and compare it to the `FileAttributes` flags enumeration.

```
var dirsAndFiles = new DirectoryInfo(target).EnumerateFileSystemInfos(); 
Console.WriteLine("Folders and files in this directory:\n"); 
foreach (var i in dirsAndFiles) { 
    var type = (i.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory ? "Directory" : "File";

    Console.WriteLine($"{type} > {i.Name}"); 
}
```

The `FileSystemInfo.Name` property will return either the file's name (in case of a file) or the last directory in the hierarchy (for a directory)--so just the subdirectory name and not the full path ("sub" instead of "c:\sub").

Comment: Written on my phone so haven't been able to verify any typos in the code